# Dropdown within card bleeding into next column of card-columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having a bizzare issue using the [card-columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns) layout when I have my cards contain dropdown menus.

The dropdown-menu divs of the bottom cards are bleeding into the next column (despite the menu appearing to be in the correct place). This only occurs when the dropdown menu drops down (not drops up--this occurs when the display window is too short to drop the menu down).

This can be seen in the below code snippet. Make sure the window is large enough so that `Card 2`'s dropdown menu drops down and not up. Then notice the Change name and Delete buttons can only be clicked by placing the cursor near `Card 3`.

[image]

It's seen here that `Card 2`'s `Make Copy` option is highlighted despite the mouse cursor being far out of position, all the way in the next column.

I am using Chrome 60.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card name</h4>
        <p class="card-text">I am some text</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="moreActionsDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">More actions</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <button class="dropdown-item">Change name</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item">Make copy</button>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <button class="dropdown-item text-danger">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end card 1-->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card name</h4>
        <p class="card-text">I am some text</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="moreActionsDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">More actions</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <button class="dropdown-item">Change name</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item">Make copy</button>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <button class="dropdown-item text-danger">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end card 2-->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card name</h4>
        <p class="card-text">I am some text</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="moreActionsDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">More actions</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <button class="dropdown-item">Change name</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item">Make copy</button>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <button class="dropdown-item text-danger">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end card 3-->
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>some content below here</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there a way to make `Card 2`'s dropdown behave as one would expect?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change the ID on the buttons `#moreActionsDropdown` ID should be unique

Comment: They are unique in my application (though I should have kept them unique in my snippet to avoid that confusion). The problem is not that the dialogs wont appear, its just that the actual location of the dropdown buttons and the "displayed" location are not the same for the second card. They can be clicked by placing the cursor after card 3 after opening card 2's menu.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm that's very weird, the main problem is that once the dropdown of the card2 is shown it's actually placed somehow inside of card3 and then using translate is positioned below the card2 button which is probably what is causing all of this.

The exact reason I don't know, but I've learned the hard way that Bootstrap sucks especially the beta. I can only recommend using something like Foundation if you haven't already put much effort into it

[image: Weird positioned element]